# Class referenced in the manifest, io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication, was not found in the project or the libraries

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, android-manifest, manifest

need some help I am just new to flutter and don't know what is the error on my AndroidManifest.xml file.In android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" ,android:name=".MainActivity". also in Metadata has errors. I don't know if the file is corrupted or not, I have opened other Android flutter projects and it has all the same error on the AndroidManifest.xml file but the APP was running with no errors or anything. now the permissions I add is not working.

`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCES_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCES_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

<!-- io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication is an android.app.Application that
     calls FlutterMain.startInitialization(this); in its onCreate method.
     In most cases you can leave this as-is, but you if you want to provide
     additional functionality it is fine to subclass or reimplement
     FlutterApplication and put your custom class here. -->
<application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:label="clima"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
             the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
             while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
             to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
          android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
          />
        <!-- Displays an Android View that continues showing the launch screen
             Drawable until Flutter paints its first frame, then this splash
             screen fades out. A splash screen is useful to avoid any visual
             gap between the end of Android's launch screen and the painting of
             Flutter's first frame. -->
        <meta-data
          android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
          android:resource="@drawable/launch_background"
          />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
         This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="flutterEmbedding"
        android:value="2" />
</application>
```

`

Comment: if you got any solution then please update the answer I also stuck in this error .. !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's normal because the Flutter SDK doesn't have code check for Android code. Even if there are warnings thrown from the Android code, you should still be able to run the Flutter app if the Android code doesn't have "real" errors.

What you can do here is to enable code completion for Java/Kotlin on `Preferences > Language & Frameworks > Flutter > Experiments`. This should remove the warnings thrown on the Android project even if the code is correct.

... or click on `Tools > Flutter > Open Android module in Android Studio`. This should open the Android build of the Flutter project on Android Studio and help check if the warnings given are correct.